# How do I call a Javascript function on the back end Vb.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, scriptmanager

I have these functions and I need to use them in them from the back end using:
**UI.ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript**
Do I need to change the functions or should I just be able to refer to them like they are.
The functions are boostraps for calendars and a time picker.

```
  $('#timepicker').timepicker({
                uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4'
            });

            $('#timepicker2').timepicker({
                uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4'
            });



  $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
                if ($(this).attr("id") == "Radiobtn1") {
                    $(".datePicker1").show();
                    $(".datePicker2").hide();
                } else if ($(this).attr("id") == "Radiobtn2") {
                    $(".datePicker2").show();
                    $(".datePicker1").hide();
                }
            });
 $(document).ready(function () {
                var date_input1 = $('input[id="date1"]'); // date input has the name "date"
                var container = $('.cal1 form').length > 0 ? $('.cal1 form').parent() : "body";
                date_input1.datepicker({
                    format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
                    container: container,
                    todayHighlight: true,
                    autoclose: true
                })

                var date_input2 = $('input[id="date2"]'); // date input has the name "date2"
                var container = $('.cal2 form').length > 0 ? $('.cal2 form').parent() : "body";
                date_input2.datepicker({
                    format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
                    container: container,
                    todayHighlight: true,
                    autoclose: true
                })
            })
```

Comment: You don't "use" that code in the backend. The whole point of `RegisterStartupScript` is that it adds some script to a page that is then executed client-side when that page is loaded into a browser. What exactly is it that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to use that code in the form I'm loading on the front end. Right now I can't because I'm loading the form with visible = false and the javascript does nothing.